# Redirect output of Xterm to log file

Tags: bash, centos, centos7, xterm

I have not been able to find an answer to this problem.
I have three programs kicked off in xterm for a demonstration automation script. I need to log the results of the xterm windows. Right now, my script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash/sh

echo "NOTE - THIS PROCESS TAKES APPROXIMATELY 60 SECONDS TO RUN"

    cd ~/myProject/ProgramOne
    xterm -e ProgramOne progone.config 2>&1 /tmp/logs/p1.txt &

    cd ~/myProject/ProgramTwo
    xterm -e ProgramOne progtwo.config 2>&1 /tmp/logs/p2.txt &

    cd ~/myProject/ProgramThree
    xterm -e ProgramOne progthree.config 2>&1 /tmp/logs/p3.txt &


# allow the scripts to collect data
sleep 60

# kill the xterm sessions from running since this is just a demonstration
pkill -9 xterm

echo "******************************************"
echo "START PROGRAMS SCRIPT COMPLETE"
echo "******************************************"
```

I have verified that `~/myProject/ProgramOne` and `~/myProject/ProgramTwo` and `~/myProject/ProgramThree` all exist, as does `/tmp/logs/*`

**The files get created, they just simply have nothing in them and do NOT contain the output of the xterm windows, which I can see popup with hundreds of lines of information.**

Comment: In no way shape or form can I see how that comment was constructive.

Comment: It implies that the script you're showing is not the same as the script you're running (unless you actually have a shell at `/bin/bash/sh` for some reason). If we see errors in your code, we can't tell whether they're errors in the code you're running or transcription errors. It's always best to copy-and-paste your actual running code into the question. See [mcve].

Comment: That is my code, line for line, it runs for me on my system.

Comment: How are you invoking it? If you're running it as `sh script_name` or `bash script_name`, then the `#!` line is ignored. If you want to run it without specifying which shell to use, as `./script_name` for example (that's the whole point of `#!`) then the `#!` line is incorrect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: by running ./script_name

Works fine with how I currently have it written.

Comment: That's very surprising. What OS are you running? What does `ls -l /bin/bash/sh` print? (Normally `/bin/bash` is the executable for the Bash shell, and `/bin/bash/sh`  can't exist because `/bin/bash` is not a directory.) When I run your script on my system, I get `bash: ./script_name: /bin/bash/sh: bad interpreter: Not a directory`

Comment: @KeithThompson CentOS7. Listing the contents of /bin/bash/sh yells because it is not a directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181971/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-jerry-m).

Comment: I just tried this on CentOS 7. A script starting with `#!/bin/bash/sh` gives `-bash: ./foo: /bin/bash/sh: bad interpreter: Not a directory` if I try to execute it. (If I insert a space between the `#` and the `!`, it executes, because it's not a valid shebang.)

Comment: I use it every day and it works for me, so I don't know why that is, perhaps you should open a question about it?

Comment: I included a script in chat. Did you try copy-and-pasting it and running it your system? (Not much point in me posting a question, since I can't reproduce the behavior.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following change in the command worked:

```
xterm -e ProgramOne progone.config 2>&1 /tmp/logs/p1.txt &
```

to

```
xterm -e 'ProgramOne progone.config 2>&1 | tee /tmp/logs/p1.txt' &
```

Answer (score 2):

`xterm` doesn't write to stdout; rather it displays the output of whatever command it invokes in its window.  You need to redirect the output of `ProgramOne`, not the output of `xterm`.

And something I didn't notice when I initially wrote this answer: your redirection is incorrect. You're passing `/tmp/logs/p1.txt` as an argument to `xterm`. The `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, but does not take a file name argument. (Yes, you can mix redirections with program arguments. For example, `echo >hello.out hello` will write `hello` to `hello.out`)

For example change

```
xterm -e ProgramOne progone.config 2>&1 /tmp/logs/p1.txt &
```

to

```
xterm -e 'ProgramOne progone.config >/tmp/logs/p1.txt 2>&1' &
```

(I'm assuming that you want to send `ProgramOne`'s stdout and stderr to `tmp/logs/p1.txt`.)

(You could also tell `xterm` to log its output to a file, using the `-l` option, but that might be disabled and the output could include formatting characters that you probably don't want.)

Comment: I just tried this solution. The file p1.txt was empty, but the name of the xterm window changed from ProgramOne to p1.txt

Comment: -l is indeed disabled :(